# How I can call get_terms() from plugin in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How I can call function I defined in functions.php from my plugin in Wordpress?
Here is my simple function from functions.php file:

```
function get_slider_tax(){
    $taxonomies = get_terms('slider-type');
    return $taxonomies;
}
```

When I call it from plugin php file it returns error "Undefined function", but when I defining this function in plugin file it returns WP_Error. So I cant get valid array of taxonomies from plugin and can't call function from plugin.

**UPD:**
I found that *get_terms return invalid taxonomy error because: you have a custom taxonomy registered in the "init" hook so in the wp-admin it doesn´t work -> your taxonomy is registered after you call "get_term"*

So, actualy, even now I cant figure out how to call it before init.

**UPD:** Actualy I dont know how I fixed it but maybe will be usefull for someone. Maybe the reason for that was that I call function before init event. I don't know exactly, In my plugin I made wrapper function for function from functions.php:

```
function custom_function(){ 
    $slider_names = array();
    $slider_tax = get_slider_tax();//Function from functions.php
    foreach($slider_tax as $slider_name){
        array_push($slider_names,$slider_name->name);
}
}
```

And then in the end of plugin's file I added init hook with wrapper function:

```
add_action('init','custom_function');
```

Comment: Need to add that I included file wp-load.php to my plugin file but it wasn't the solution of problem.

Comment: use add_action `('inti','get_slider_tax')` to register your function by wordpress action hooks

Comment: @Jothi Kannan, it's strange but even this doesn't help..
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_slider_tax()

Comment: You can try  method here :
  [1]: http://justin.ag/technology/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-plugin-custom-functions-php/

Comment: Do not include `wp-load.php` in your plugin. All WordPress is available to your plugin. You are not showing how `get_slider_tax` is being called. Also, if you're [creating a plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615), `functions.php` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: btw - Is there a reason why you can not just move that function to your plugin file. also, can you post the call itself from plugin ??

Comment: @Obmerk Kronen, that is the main problem - I cant move this code from functions to plugin. It returns WP-Error.

Comment: @brasofilo Here is how I'm calling it from plugin:

`$slider_names = array();
     $slider_tax = get_slider_tax();
     foreach($slider_tax['name'] as $slider_name){
      array_push($slider_names,$slider_name);
     }`